# How to do a cyclic doubly link list add method in java

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing the add(E) method in the cyclic DoublyLinkedList class as well as the Node inner class.

Node should be implemented as a private inner class.

DoublyLinkedList's "first" attribute should point to the first node in the list. Its "size" attribute should store the number of elements in the list.

I am struggling on my add method, because it feels like nothing is wrong and I don't know what else I can add this this code that can fix it.

Therefore a brief introduction on what the add method should do.

The add(E) method should add the value parameter to the end of the list. Be sure to address the case in which the list is empty and/or the added element is the first in the list.

Here's my code:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E>
{
private Node first;
private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void add(E value)
{
    if(first == null)
    {
        first = new Node(value, null, null);
        first.next = first;
        first.prev = first;
    }
    else
    {
        first = new Node(value, first.next, first.prev);
        first.next = first.prev;
        first = first.next;
        first.prev = first;
    }
    size++;
}
private class Node<E>
{
    private E data;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;

    public Node(E data, Node next, Node prev)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: To clarify for others reading this, I assume that cyclic means this is a circular linked list. Which why if size == 1, then first->next = first=>prev = first.

Comment: @rcgldr I'm sorry that's confusing. so is the way I have wrong?

Comment: It was just clarification. I assume your class called it cyclic instead of circular. Some reading this may not realize it means the same thing.

Comment: @AdanVivero - Although, you seem to have got your answer here; yet thought I might want to share something more for future readers of this thread. After a lot of thought in this area over the weekend, I felt that having a circular data structure may not be a good idea. What you are intending to do here is access the data structure in a cyclic manner, and accessing the data is something different how data is actually stored. Think about "Separation of Responsibilities" here. Ideally in your case, you might want to return an iterator from your class and have implement the concept of cyclic reads

Comment: @RahulR. That's exactly what I'm working on. A cyclic one, but many don't seem to know it. Do you know how to fix it? Also, if you don't mind, I sort of need help on a get method, I have it on another question, it's tied to this same code.

Comment: @AdanVivero - I have updated my answer that implements separation of responsibility, in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code fixed with minimal change (just the else case in add):

```
class DoublyLinkedList<E>
{
    private Node first;
    private int size;

    public void add(E value)
    {
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = new Node(value, null, null);
            first.next = first;
            first.prev = first;
        }
        else
        {
            first.prev.next = new Node(value, first, first.prev);
            first.prev = first.prev.next;
        }
        size++;
    }

    private class Node<E>
    {
        private E data;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;

        public Node(E data, Node next, Node prev)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explanation of else {...} in add(): new Node(...) sets data, new.next = first, new.prev = last. first.prev.next = new Node(...) sets last.next = new node. first.prev = first.prev.next sets first.prev to new node, which is the new last node.

Comment: you were terrific help on this one, do you think you could help me on my get method, I posted another question..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

One mistake is here: Instead of this line this.next = prev; it should have this.prev = prev;

However, if you fix this line the code will still not work. This is a simplified version of your code that works.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {

    private static class Node<E> {

        private final E data;
        private Node<E> next;
        private Node<E> prev;

        Node(E data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = this;
            this.prev = this;
        }

        Node(E data, Node<E> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            next.prev = this;
        }
    }

    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;
    private int size;

    public void add(E value) {
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = new Node<>(value);
            this.tail = head;
        } else {
            this.head = new Node<>(value, head);
            this.head.prev = this.tail;
            this.tail.next = head;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void forEach(Consumer<E> consumer) {
        Node<E> node = this.head;

        if (node != null) {
            do {
                consumer.accept(node.data);
                node = node.next;
            } while (node != this.head);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);

        list.forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + ", "));
    }

}
```

What I've done: in order to create a circular double linked list I keep a reference to the tail.

Comment: The goal is to create a circular linked list. first.prev == last, first.next = second, last.prev = next to last, last.next = first.

Comment: would last be first.next?

Comment: @AdanVivero Yes. The implementation is a circular list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation for your case -

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {

    // A reference to the root node
    private Node<E> root = null;

    // attribute for storing the size of the linked list
    private int countOfNodes = 0;

    // attribute that indicates if the linked list would be iterated in a cycle
    private boolean isCircular = false;

    /**
     * The linked list Node class
     * 
     * @param <E>
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    class Node<E> {
        // attribute for storing the value
        private E data;

        // attributes for storing the linked list references
        private Node<E> previousNode = null;
        private Node<E> nextNode = null;

        public Node() {
            super();
        }

        public Node(E data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Node<E> getPreviousNode() {
            return previousNode;
        }

        public void setPreviousNode(Node<E> previousNode) {
            this.previousNode = previousNode;
        }

        public Node<E> getNextNode() {
            return nextNode;
        }

        public void setNextNode(Node<E> nextNode) {
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

        public E getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(E data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The iterator implementation
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    class DoublyLinkedListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
        private Node<E> currentNode = null;

        public DoublyLinkedListIterator(Node<E> startNode) {
            super();
            this.currentNode = startNode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (this.currentNode != null);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public E next() {
            E data = currentNode.getData();
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();

            if (currentNode == null && DoublyLinkedList.this.isCircular()) {
                this.currentNode = (Node<E>) DoublyLinkedList.this.getRoot();
            }

            return data;
        }
    }

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean isCircular() {
        return this.isCircular;
    }

    public void setCircular(boolean isCircular) {
        this.isCircular = isCircular;
    }

    public Node<E> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(Node<E> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.countOfNodes;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new DoublyLinkedListIterator<>(this.getRoot());
    }

    public void add(E value) {
        Node<E> node = new Node<E>(value);
        addAfter(getLastNode(), node);
        this.countOfNodes++;
    }

    public Node<E> getLastNode() {  
        Node<E> lastNode = null;

        Node<E> node = getRoot();
        while (node != null) {
            lastNode = node;
            node = node.getNextNode();
        }

        return lastNode;
    }

    public void addAfter(Node<E> parentNode, E value) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(value);
        addAfter(parentNode, newNode);
    }

    public void addAfter(Node<E> parentNode, Node<E> newNode) {
        if (parentNode == null) {
            this.setRoot(newNode);
        } else {
            parentNode.setNextNode(newNode);
        }
    }

    public void addBefore(Node<E> parentNode, E value) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(value);
        addBefore(parentNode, newNode);
    }

    public void addBefore(Node<E> parentNode, Node<E> newNode) {
        if (parentNode == null) {
            this.setRoot(newNode);
        } else {
            Node<E> prevNode = parentNode.getPreviousNode();
            parentNode.setPreviousNode(newNode);
            newNode.setNextNode(parentNode);            
            newNode.setPreviousNode(prevNode);

            if (newNode.getPreviousNode() == null) {
                this.setRoot(newNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, following is a test -

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class DoublyLinkedListTest {
    private final int initialSize = 4;

    private DoublyLinkedList<String> list = new DoublyLinkedList<String>() {{
        setCircular(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++) {
            add("Data " + (i + 1));
        }
    }};

    public DoublyLinkedListTest() {
        super();
    }

    @Test
    void testListSize() {
        if (list.size() != initialSize) {
            fail(String.format("Expected value for the list's size is %d, whereas obtained value is %d", 4, list.size()));
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testLastElement() {
        String lastAddedValue = list.getLastNode().getData();
        String expectedValue = "Data 4";

        if (!expectedValue.equals(lastAddedValue)) {
            fail(String.format("Expected value for the last node is %s, whereas obtained value is %s", expectedValue, lastAddedValue));
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testAddElementOnTop() {
        list.addBefore(list.getRoot(), "Data 5");

        String lastAddedValue = list.getRoot().getData();
        String expectedValue = "Data 5";

        if (!expectedValue.equals(lastAddedValue)) {
            fail(String.format("Expected value for the last node is %s, whereas obtained value is %s", expectedValue, lastAddedValue));
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testCircularIteration() {
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

        int counter = 0;
        final int expectedValue = (initialSize + 1) * 2;

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            counter++;

            if (counter == expectedValue) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (counter != expectedValue) {
            fail(String.format("Expected value for the iteration count is %d, whereas obtained value is %d", expectedValue, counter));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help with what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AdanVivero - Edited the code to add elements to the top.

Comment: Modified the code to implement separation of responsibilities, i.e. the way the data is actually stored is separated from the way data is intended to be read, which in this context could optionally be "circular".

Comment: Thanks, but I have specific guidelines on how they want my code to be set up with certain methods, and private class etc. Therefore, the work needs to be within my add method.