# Iterator for something generated recursively (without pre-generating the results)

Tags: java, recursion, iterator, iteration

I want to create an `Iterator` in Java (i.e. support `hasNext()` and `next()` calls). However, the thing I'm iterating is generated recursively. I want to be able to create this `Iterator` without having to generate the values beforehand and storing them. Instead, the `next()` call should get the next value that the recursion outputs, and `hasNext()` should check that the recursion is not yet done.

Is there a standard pattern for doing this?

Edit: I think a Python `yield` in a recursive function is the functionality I'm looking for. Not sure how to do it in Java though.

Comment: Check out my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190980/how-to-do-a-cyclic-doubly-link-list-add-method-in-java/55191433#55191433). May be this is what you are looking for, if not then at least could offer some hints.

Comment: Can you show an example of the recursive algorithm?   Using iterators it's often possible to convert a recursive algorithm into an iterative one by retaining the state between calls to `next()`.

Comment: I figured out an iterative solution to my specific problem: I was trying to generate all subsets of a certain size for a given set. I do this iteratively now by incrementing a set of indices on the original set. I'll leave the question open though, since I think there are definitely algorithms where it's difficult to get an iterative solution.

Comment: See e.g.http://jdoodle.com/a/15tZ, where I've generated an O(1) algorithm using iterators to generate each member of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration