# Linking nodes within a Circular Doubly Linked Structure

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have been working on this Circular Doubly Linked Structure for a week now, and I am stuck on this add method. I cannot get the nodes to link correctly, as when I run the program to print out the list it just is not what I would expect. Below I attached my DNode (just a normal node class) code, along with the ListCDLS (Circular Doubly Linked Structure) code, and the unexpected output I received. I have tried many different algorithms within the add method, but to no avail. The only one that works correctly is the first if statement block.

```
public class DNode {
   
   private Object item;
   private DNode next;
   private DNode back;

   public DNode(Object item) {
       this.item = item;
       next = this;
       back = this;
   }
   
   public DNode(Object item, DNode nextNode, DNode backNode) {
       this.item = item;
       this.next = nextNode;
       this.back = backNode;
   }
\\omitted getters and setters for all data fields
```

```
public class ListCDLS implements ListInterface {
    
    private DNode tail;
    private int numItems;
    
    public ListCDLS() {
        tail = null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(this.size() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return numItems;
    }
   
    public void add(int index, Object item) throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if(isValidIndex(index)) {
            if(this.isEmpty()) {
                DNode head = new DNode(item);
                tail = head;
            }
            //this is the one i am struggling with
            else if(index == 0 && !this.isEmpty()) {                
                DNode nextIndex = tail.getNext();
                DNode newHead = new DNode(item, nextIndex, tail);
                tail.setNext(newHead);
                tail.setBack(find(numItems-2));
                nextIndex.setBack(newHead);
                nextIndex.setNext(find(index+2));
            }
            else {
                
                //code I didn't start yet for the case of adding at index 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

            }
            numItems++;
        }
        else {
            throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException("The index is out of bounds!");
        }
    }

    private DNode find(int index) {
        DNode current;
        int possibleIndicies = numItems - 1;
        

        if( (possibleIndicies/2) < index ) {
            current = tail.getNext();
            
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)  {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            
        }
        else {
            current = tail;
            
            for(int i = possibleIndicies; i > index; i--)  {
                current = current.getBack();
            }
            
        }   

        return current;
    }
```

So, the input I would do would be:

Item: 6, Index: 0
Item: 5, Index: 0
Item: 4, Index: 0
Item: 3, Index: 0
Item: 2, Index: 0
Item: 1, Index: 0
Item: 0, Index: 0

So the expected output would be:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Although, I receive:
6, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6

Any help would be very appreciated. I do not understand how else to go about this, as I feel I have exhausted all possibilities, although I know I am wrong with that assumption.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190980/how-to-do-a-cyclic-doubly-link-list-add-method-in-java If not, did you try searching for the terms ___circular doubly linked list java___ ?

Comment: When writing operations on data structures like that, what helped me much was to draw the list and arrows that represent pointers and just execute multiple operations visually. This is easier than trying to imagine everything in your head or by looking at code. Try that out if you haven't already.